# How to organize imports with blanks between packages?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, intellij-14

I manage to organize my imports like this

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
```

with this setting:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqKaE.png]

How do I organize them like this (blank between each different package group) ?

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
```

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl + Alt + O` . This is for `organize import` in intelliJ

Comment: @Adi Yes, that is not the problem, it's about >>how<< IntellIj organizes the imports. It's about using the same settings as Eclipse users an avoiding unnecessary diffs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings/Editor/Code Style/Java and click on the Imports tab.

In the bottom half of the screen you can arrange the layout, including adding blank lines, separating static imports etc

Comment: I don't see an option to add blank lines between all top-level packages. Only a way to explicitly add blank lines between specific packages.